# "You should go to school" vs "You must go to school"

Tags: modal-verbs

What is the difference between these two sentences:

> 1. You **should** go to school.
> 2. You **must** go to school.

And when should I use them?

Answer (score 5):

Describing modal auxiliaries in English is difficult because most of them can have multiple meanings, and sometimes the exact same sentence can have different interpretations depending on context.

> You must go to school.

This could mean:

1. **Obligation or necessity**　*(deontic modality)*

   > You can *not* end up like your old man.  You *must* go to school.

   I believe it is necessary that you go to school.  This is a strongly worded statement of obligation. This sounds relatively stiff and formal.

   Because it's so strongly worded, it's more likely to be used for attending school in general rather than physically going to school on a specific day:

   > You have class today.  You must go to school or you'll be late.

   This is possible, but sounds rather stiff and awkward.
2. **Inference**　*(epistemic modality)*

   > Wow, you're smart!  You must go to school!

   I believe based on inferences from observations I've made that it is highly likely you go to school.  This doesn't sound stiff or formal.

> You should go to school.

This probably means:

- **Obligation or necessity**　*(deontic modality)*

  > You have class today, right?  You should go to school.

  I believe it is a good idea for you go to school.  This is less strongly worded, and doesn't sound as stiff or formal as *must*.

  Because it's not as strongly worded, it's easier to imagine this refers to attending school on a specific day, rather than the more important idea of attending school in general.  The alternative is possible, though:

  > I want you to do something with your life.  You should go to school and study engineering.

  This isn't as stiff or formal as the version with *must*.

With this particular example, the other meanings of *should* are hard to imagine.

*Should* is more common than *must* overall.  *Must* is significantly more common in British English than in American English, particularly in conversation, where American speakers use *must* much less frequently.  (Source: *Longman Grammar of Spoken and Written English*, Biber et al 1999, p.488.)

Comment: At least in British English, "must" indicates absolute obligation, whereas "should" is merely a recommendation. "You must go to school" means that it is forbidden for you to not go; "You should go to school" means that it is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

*Should* is saying there will be advantages to you if you go to school, or negative consequences if you don't go to school.  The speaker/writer is persuading you to go.

*Must* is saying you are required to go to school.  The speaker/writer is compelling you to go.

Now, if you don't do something that you must do, of course there will be negative consequences, but those would be typically stronger than if one said *should*.

> You must go through that door to leave the building.

You have to go through the door to leave.  If you don't go through the door, you won't be able to leave.

Saying:

> You should go through that door to leave the building

implies that there are other ways out of the building, and that the speaker/writer is recommending this to you.

*Should* is also used in place of *must* if the speaker is trying to be polite or gentle.

Comment: what kind of stronger? what's the barrier between the weak and strong consequences?

Comment: There's no fixed rules, but as a start, something that is required by law, rules and regulations, parents, etc. would fall under "must".

Comment: In the negative form of must .. for example you mustn't eat that .. is it possible to use "can't" instead? and does the meaning change in you can't eat that

Comment: You can.  *You can't do X* can also mean there is no physical way for you to do X, but *You mustn't do X* won't ever mean that.  E.g., *You can't walk through that brick wall.* - *must* should not be used there.

Answer (score 0):

These are modal auxiliaries. Different auxiliaries indicate different things.

should: suggestion or advice.
must: necessity.

Comment: Any advice will always be taken as help. I will take care of that too.